# How do i unwrap a cylinder to be able to use tiling textures?

Tags: texturing, uv

I want to make modular tunnel pieces with cylinders. but I don't know how to unwrap the cylinder in a way that allows the use of tileable textures.

an example is the substance designer rounded cylinder

[image: The Square is the uv space, all the rest sit outside of it but it still tiles perfectly]

Comment: why not the Cylinder Projection option?